# Set global defaults for Catalina Music "as Songs" display

Tags: catalina, music.app

In Catalina Music, as in iTunes, choosing View/as Songs  shows songs in a column layout that I prefer.  However, Music defaults to the following columns, which I don't like:

```
Title, Cloud Download, Time, Artist, Album, Genre, Love, Plays
```

The only ones I want are Title, Time, Artist, and Album, and there are other ones I want that aren't in the list.  It's easy to choose columns in an individual (EDIT) playlist (either by control-clicking on the header bar, or with command-J, which brings up a convenient checkbox dialog).  But it's a real pain when you have hundreds of separate (EDIT) playlists (one for each album), as I do.  I have to do this separately in *each* playlists.

Is there some way to change the default globally?  (I'm willing to edit configuration files if that's what it takes.)

(btw I experienced this problem about a year ago when I first installed Catalina on a different machine, and didn't solve the problem, but I have gradually fixed folders bit by bit on that machine.  Now I have a new machine with all of the old defaults.  I'm surprised I didn't ask earlier, and surprised that someone else has posted this question by now.  I see no evidence of either.)

Comment: I don't get it. If I open music.app (Catalina) and select songs in the sidebar it shows **ALL** of my songs in a long list sorted by what column is selected. If I don't want a particular column I just right click and un check it. And it says that way. You may need to clarify what you are trying to do with a screen capture and further explanation.

Comment: Thanks @SteveChambers.  I revised to clarify.  I wrote "folders", but I should have written "playlists".  (These are organized into playlist folders, but that's not the important point.)  So the problem is that what you're describing is correct, but I have to do it hundreds of times, once for each playlist.  I don't usually use the list of all songs. I choose from albums (in playlists) or artists (in folders) that I have organized the way that I want.  I want to apply the changes globally for all of them at once, and ideally to set a default that will apply to all new playlists (as in iTunes).

Comment: OK I see what you are doing but they are not "folders" they are "playlists" as a Command-N gives you a new playlist not a new folder (see: "File > New" menu) Looks like the only way to get a playlist to remember the columns is to duplicate a playlist that you already made, rename it and then add songs to it. Not ideal.

Comment: Thanks @SteveChambers.  That's a great idea.  It won't help with the old playlists, but it will help with the new ones.  I can keep an empty playlist just for this purpose.